# How to throw three exception in boolean method?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am new to the Java World and I am trying to understand exceptions but what I didnt get is; 
     How can I throw an exception in boolean method?
     And what to do when I have to use three Exceptions in one catch?

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        try {
            if (Assert.isNull(bean)) {
                logger.info(EXC_MSG_BEAN_NULL, bean.toString());
            }

            String dependentFieldActualValue;
            dependentFieldActualValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, dependentField);
            boolean isActualEqual = stringEquals(dependentFieldValue, dependentFieldActualValue);

            if (isActualEqual == ifInequalThenValidate) {
                return true;
            }
            return isTargetValid(bean, ctx);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.info("Necessary attributes can't be accessed: {}", e.getMessage());
//I cant throw an exception here...

        }
    }
```

or i can do this but it didnt also helped me: I have no idea how to use exception in boolean method.

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        try {
            if (Assert.isNull(bean)) {
                logger.info(EXC_MSG_BEAN_NULL, bean.toString());
            }

            String dependentFieldActualValue;
            dependentFieldActualValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, dependentField);
            boolean isActualEqual = stringEquals(dependentFieldValue, dependentFieldActualValue);

            if (isActualEqual == ifInequalThenValidate) {
                return true; 
            }
            return isTargetValid(bean, ctx); 
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            logger.info("Necessary attributes can't be accessed: {}", e.getMessage());
            //Here should be my throw new ReflectiveOperationException("ERROR");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? What do you want to do when you encounter one of those three?

Comment: My `getProperty()`- Method need it. and when something goes wrong there I want to see it. `public static String getProperty(Object bean, String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
        return BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getProperty(bean, name);
    }`

Comment: and why can't you throw the exceptions? a simple `throw e;` will do. maybe you need to alter the method signature, but that is

Comment: This method must always return boolean and you have one situation unhandled, where you catch exception and return nothing. Decide, what you want to return if you catch it. 

You can set defeult value which will be returned. for ex. 
                      public boolean isValid(...)    {
     (write your code in here.  If something happens, return true; )
     return false;
}

Comment: I rather would catch exceptions separately.

try {
          // some code

          } catch (Exception n) { 
          // some code
          } catch (Exception e) {
      // some code
          }

If you not get exceptions, your program gonna crush if exception happen. You can easily try this with array - try to get object from index which do not exist. You will get ArrayOutOfBoundsException and program crash.

If you put this into try catch block, and get Exception for it, you can do something else - for example print "There isnt index in this array".

Comment: A bit of advice:  Always use `e` instead of `e.getMessage()`.  An exception’s message by itself is almost never useful.  You want to log the entire stack trace, so you’ll know exactly where an exception occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't throw an exception at the indicated point because the method `isValid` doesn't include any Exception's in the signature. For pedagogical purposes, let's define a custom exception type:

```
static class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

And then we can add `throws MyException` to the method signature of `isValid` and actually throw it in the [`multi-catch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). Like,

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) throws MyException {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        logger.info("Necessary attributes can't be accessed: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new MyException(e);
    }
}
```

If you want those **specific** exceptions to return up the call stack - just add them to the throws line and remove the `try-catch` (or re-throw in the `try-catch` if you ***really*** want to log here for some reason).

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    // No try-catch. Otherwise the same.
}
```

Comment: Will need to alter the Interface or whatever is `Overridden`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to work with exception:

- Do something with it now
- Throw it (do something with it later)

As I understand you can't throw exception there because your method doesn't allow to throw exception, so you should deal with all checked exceptions within this method. Or you can add keyword "throws":

```
isValid(...) throws NoSuchMethodException {

...

throw e;

}
```

and this would allow you to throw exception of class NoSuchMethodException.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to catch the three exceptions you expected,but in java ,any exception you don’t catch or throw it,the java application will crash.you do like this is nonsense

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your class is implementing `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator`. The signature of the method `isValid` is defined in that interface as `boolean isValid(T value, ConstraintValidatorContext context);`. That's why you can't throw a checked exception from your implementation - you would violate the interface. Otherwise, if you were implementing a method in a class which doesn't implement any interface, or implements some interface you can change, you'd be able to change the method signature and throw exceptions at will.